# How to calculate max buy and sell amounts of a token in Uniswap v3 pool?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

I'm trying to calculate the maximum amount that I can receive in the uniswap v3 pool without changing the price (within the price tick).

Example: Pool: https://etherscan.io/address/0xEe55980166F1746e5978F724995aedc3cb06d553#readContract https://info.uniswap.org/#/pools/0xee55980166f1746e5978f724995aedc3cb06d553

How do I calculate how much I can get amount of USDT when selling the maximum amount of Suter? Given the price tick and current liquidity (we are on the verge of a price range).

Thank you!